# The selected value of the select attribute is not displayed. TypeScript/Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I don't see anything in the item selection window. The elements are loaded from the Web APi server. Here is the [photo of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B886H.png).

### Component class

```
carsDynamic!: Array<Car>

private loadDynamicData(){
  this.dynamic.getDynamicCars().subscribe((data: Car[]) => {
  this.carsDynamic = data
})
```

### HTML page

```
<select  class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="editedSale.carId">
  <option disabled selected>--Select--</option>  
  <option *ngFor="let car of carsDynamic"  
          value={{car.id}}>  
          {{car.brandName}}  
  </option>  
</select>
```

How to fix this problem ?

Comment: Doesn't carsDynamic have to be declared as public?

Comment: Add in your troubleshooting so it's verified that you're receiving the data, and the data is in the format you're expecting. Also, `[value]="car.id"` is a better way of coding that

Comment: @Kinglish I get the data and can even use it to edit other data of which they are a part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause of the malfunction. The fact is that I downloaded the wrong data model from the server

Answer (score 0):

Problem originates from `[(ngModel)]="editedSale.carId"`. You have to choose, either template driven from or reactive form.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'select-reset-example',
  templateUrl: 'select-reset-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['select-reset-example.css'],
})
export class SelectResetExample {
  dynamic = new ReplaySubject<any>(1);
  carsDynamic: any[];
  data = [
    { id: 1, brandName: 'Audi' },
    { id: 2, brandName: 'BMW' },
  ];

  constructor() {
    this.loadDynamicData();
    this.dynamic.next(this.data);
  }

  private loadDynamicData() {
    this.dynamic.subscribe((data: Car[]) => {
      this.carsDynamic = data;
    });
  }

  onSelect(event: any) {
    console.log(event.target.value);
  }
}

export interface Car {
  id: number;
  brandName: string;
}
```

```html
<select class="form-control" (change)="onSelect($event)">
  <option disabled selected>--Select--</option>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let car of carsDynamic">
    <option value="{{car | json}}">{{car.brandName}}</option>
  </ng-container>
</select>

<select class="form-control" (change)="onSelect($event)">
  <option disabled selected>--Select--</option>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let car of carsDynamic">
    <option value="{{car.id}}">{{car.brandName}}</option>
  </ng-container>
</select>

<select class="form-control" (change)="onSelect($event)">
<option disabled selected>--Select--</option>
<ng-container *ngFor="let car of carsDynamic">
  <option value="{{car.brandName}}">{{car.brandName}}</option>
</ng-container>
</select>
```

Look into console log.
Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-matselect-ybbg2t?file=app%2Fselect-reset-example.ts

Comment: Console log shows me the id, but i still doesn't see needed parameter

Comment: What parameter are you looking for? You said you don't see anything. Now you see something. With `{{car | json}}` you can get all the data there is about `car`.

Comment: I'm looking for brandName. The ID values are passed to the correct one , but the select list still does not display the brandName field .

Comment: I have added 3rd option to get `brandName` with `<option value="{{car.brandName}}">{{car.brandName}}</option>`.

Comment: It seems to me that I have found a problem: for some reason, the brandName values returned from the server are empty